# Impossible to convert data to int using getBytes

Tags: swift, swift4

```
let objectData: Data = .....
var intValue: Int = 0
objectData.getBytes(&intValue, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size) // there is an error
return intValue
```

the compiler says is

> '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'Int'

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

By the way, `NSData` works properly

```
var intValue: Int = 0
(objectData as NSData).getBytes(&intValue, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
return intValue
```

Comment: `Data` doesn't seem to have a function `getBytes` are you sure this is your actual code? I can only see `getBytes` for `NSData`, but that require an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to a buffer, not an `Int`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1411450-getbytes

Comment: nope . optional did not helped

Comment: @Vyacheslav chaiging `intValue` to have type `Int?` and casting `objectData` to `NSData` makes your code compile and run just fine for me

Comment: @DávidPásztor it works without optional. The NSData can help. But is there any Swift methods without bridging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data` has no `getBytes()` method. You can bridge to `NSData` (as you did),
or use the `withUnsafeBytes()` method:

```
let objectData = Data(bytes: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
let intValue: Int = objectData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
print(intValue) // 513
```

(assuming that `objectData` contains at least 8 bytes).

Inside the closure, `$0` is a pointer to the bytes, and its type
is inferred from the context as `UnsafePointer<Int>`.